# How to tell whether a recurrence equation belongs to case one or two of the master theorem

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, analysis, master-theorem

If **O**(f(x)) is always also **Theta**(f(x)) as theta is O and omega at the same time. How to tell whether a recurrence equation fits case 1 or case 2 of the master theorem.

For example, ()=4(/2)+²sqrt();

a=4,b=2 so logb(a)= 2.

Here f(n) = O(n^2) which is case 1.

But f(n) = Theta(n^2) also which is case 2.

Which one should I choose then and why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know exactly whether `f(n)` is a `O(n^logb(a))` or `Theta(n^logb(a))` a simple way would be to calculate the limit of `f(n)/n^logb(a)` when n goes to infinity.

if the limit is `infinity` then `f(n)` is `O(n^logb(a))`
and if the limit is a `finite` number then `f(n)` is `Theta(n^logb(a))`.

Answer (score 0):

Your implications seem to be switched around: Membership in `Theta(f(x))` always implies being in `O(f(x))`, not the other way around.

Cases 1 and 2 of the master theorem (as found in CLRS' *Introduction to Algorithms* or on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms))) are mutually exclusive.

Case 1 applies when `f(n)` is polynomially strictly smaller (i.e. asymptotically smaller by a factor `n^c`, `c > 0`) than `n ^ logb(a)`.

Case 2 is presented differently in several places, but applies only in situations when `f(n)` and `n ^ logb(a)` are asymptotically equal, up to a possible *polylogarithmic* multiplying factor on `n ^ logb(a)`.

In your case, `f(n)` is **not** in `O(n^2)`, even up to a polylog factor. `f(n)` is in `O(n^2.5)` (because it is in `Theta(n^2.5)`). So case 2 doesn't apply; neither does case 1. Importantly, you can **never** have overlap between any of the three cases, in either CLRS' or Wikipedia's definition. In your example, case 3 happens to apply, so more analysis and the regularity condition are needed to prove the complexity.